# Troubleshoot varnish and dual server configuration

Tags: varnish, varnish-vcl

I have Varnish set up and working with 2 server instances.

I've made changes to the default.vcl file and updated my changes as follows on both my servers:

```
$NOW = fdfdf;
sudo varnishadm -T xx.xx.xx.xx: -S /etc/varnish/secret vcl.load reload$NOW /etc/varnish/default.vcl && sudo varnishadm -T xx.xx.xx.xx: -S /etc/varnish/secret vcl.use reload$NOW"
```

One server reflects the new change and works fine, but the other still seems to be using the old configuration.

Does anyone have idea why this might be or how to troubleshoot?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1):

If you execute each command manually, does it also work? My best guesses now are:

- you're prompted for your sudo password on one system, not on the other (thus it hangs)?
- you're pointing to a secret-file with incorrect permissions?
- somehow your first varnishadm didn't return "true" and thus the vcl.use didn't trigger in the second part

So, best thing to do: execute each command manually and check the responses you get.